# Двухчасовая группировка за сутки tsql

Tags: sql-server

```
insert into dbo.twoHoursReportPP1 
SELECT datetimefromparts(datepart(year, [Datetime]), datepart(month, [Datetime]), datepart(day, [Datetime]), datepart(hour, dateadd(Hour, 0, [Datetime]))/2*2, 0, 0, 0) as [Data], 
    sum(PressOilIn_P1) as PressOilIn_P1, 
    sum(PressOilOut_P1) as PressOilOut_P1, 
    sum(PressGas_P1) as PressGas_P1, 
    avg(TempOilIn_P1) as TempOilIn_P1, 
    avg(TempOilOut_P1) as TempOilOut_P1, 
    avg(TempGas_P1) as TempGas_P1, 
    avg(TempWater_P1) as TempWater_P1, 
    sum(ConsumVOil_P1) as ConsumVOil_P1, 
    sum(ConsumMOil_P1) as ConsumMOil_P1, 
    sum(ConsumGas_PP1_2hPrev) as ConsumGas_PP1_2hPrev
FROM #temp1  
group by datetimefromparts(datepart(year, Datetime), datepart(month, Datetime), datepart(day, Datetime), (datepart(hour, dateadd(Hour, 0, [Datetime]))/2*2), 0, 0, 0) 
order by [Data] asc
```

Есть скрипт, который группирует таблицу каждые 2 часа в сутки. Но делает это таким образом: Интервал с 0 ч и 2 ч в результате запишет в строку для 0 ч, с 2-4 будет в 2ч и тд., закончится на 22ч(22-24ч). Как сделать чтобы результат был таким 2-4 результат был в 4ч. Вся результативная таблица заканчивалась на 24ч(или как то 23:59?), а начиналась на 2ч.

Comment: прибавить 2 к тому что есть

Comment: @teran, Если вы про прибавку к части .../2*2+2..., то в результате не вижу изменений, если не про это, то прошу поясните?

Comment: "Не удалось сконструировать тип данных datetime. Некоторые аргументы имеют недопустимые значения." При добавление "+2"

Comment: у вас там два этих вычисления в обоих прибавили?

Comment: В обоих, выходит ошибка, которую указал выше

Comment: группировку оставьте тогда, а в селекте переделайте на конкатенацию компонент в строку формата даты. DATETIME с видом времени в `24:00:00` вы не получите, только строку такую. Даже можете отформатировать дату в `Y-m-d X:H:s` и заменить `X` на hour/2*2+2

Comment: В слекте ругается на Datetime в списке выбора insert into dbo.twoHoursReportPP1 
 SELECT concat(datepart(year, [Datetime]), datepart(month, [Datetime]), datepart(day, [Datetime]), datepart(hour, dateadd(Hour, 0, [Datetime]))/2*2+2) as [Data],